# Name error when reading files recursively in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a recursive directory named root. First  I want to  find the top level folders.  I mean that  when I  click on the root folder, let's say I see 3 folders in it, these 3  folders are the top level folders.  Each one of those corresponds to the sub_root in the loop. I open a  csv file in each sub_root. Then recursively read the files in each sub_root, and write the meta info obtained by tinytag.

My code is below. I get a 'NameError: name 'title' is not defined'.  I am aware that in 'title=tag.filesize'  the tag.filesize is already used, I intentionally set that thinking if the error was due to filename which is commented out in my code, that should fix the error. I can't seem to find the bug.

```
top_dir_list= next(os.walk(root))[1]
for j in range(0,len(top_dir_list)):
    sub_src=top_dir_list[j]
    sub_root=os.path.join(root,sub_src)

    result_csv=os.path.join(sub_root,'metainfo.csv')
    with open(result_csv, 'w',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:    
        fieldnames=['filename','duration','filesize']  # keys.
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames) 
        csv_writer.writeheader()

        dirfiles=[]
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(sub_root):
            for item in files:
                dirfiles.append(os.path.join(path, item))
        length=len(dirfiles)
        for i in range(0,length):
            if dirfiles[i].endswith('.rar'):
                print('this is a rar file:', dirfiles[i])
            elif (dirfiles[i]).endswith(('mp3', 'wav')):
                #title=os.path.basename(dirfiles[i])
                title=tag.filesize
                tag = TinyTag.get(dirfiles[i])
                duration=tag.duration
                filesize=tag.filesize
            else:
                print("This file type is not supported:",dirfiles[i])

            csv_writer.writerow({'filename':title,'duration':duration,'filesize':filesize})
```

Comment: What if the file does not end with `mp3` or `wav`?

Comment: Hi! The list is longer actually, I just put there mp3 and wav to make the code easier to read. And if not the else statement prints that the file is not supported in the code.

Comment: Yes, the print statement prints that the file is not supported, and then the `csv_writer.writerow` statement throws an error because `title` is not defined.

Comment: @kutlus You can add `continue` for non-supported files.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I understand now. I am new in python, I couldn`t see that. But i dont understand why i got -1 vote, i really spend time to find the bug and tried to be as clear as possible when i asked the question.

Comment: My code is working now, thank you!

Comment: Next time you have a problem with your code, try to create a [mcve]. The snippet you posted here is incomplete (e.g. `os` and `root` are not defined), and it contains lots of extraneous code that is irrelevant for reproducing the error.

Comment: Since I didn`t see the bug, I thought everything might be relevant and yet tried to make it easier to read. While i appreciated your time and the help, you really made me regretted to asked my question here.